# Angular 6: how to access ALL option values in mat-autocomplete dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular6

Given the example in the Angular docs [you can see here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values) and also repeated below, how can I access the rest of the object data in `options`?

If for example, the object was more than just a simple list of names in key:value format, but something more complex such as data coming in from an API:

```
dataObject = {
  name: 'someName',
  nameID: 'someId',
  foo: 'bar'
  }
```

The example in the docs is too simple and isn't telling me how to get the `name` to display in the input field, and to also get the corresponding `nameId` in the ts file needed to return a PUT request via the API.

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Assignee" aria-label="Assignee" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

component.ts:

```
export class AutocompleteDisplayExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: User[] = [
    {name: 'Mary'},
    {name: 'Shelley'},
    {name: 'Igor'}
  ];
  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string | User>(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }

  private _filter(name: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the onSelectionChange option:

You can simple add, to the mat-option:

`(onSelectionChange)="setID(option.nameID)"`

Everytime when you select a value this will be triggered.

Comment: My word @Swoox! I think you might have done it! Thanks!