# Formatting an Angular Material Autocomplete Input

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

My task is to build an input with the Angular Material Autocomplete and numeric formatting. For the Project I've build a numeric formatter, that is used on many input fields.

The problem: Angular does not allow multiple ControlValueAccessor for one control.
So I must decide between the format-CVA and the autocomplete-CVA.

I tried a workaround with an additional hidden autocomplete input. onFocus/onBlur opens/closes the autocomplete box of the hidden input and the change event of the autocomplete writes the selected value to the visible input. But the Angular Material Autocomplete does not fire the changeevent, when it has been opened by function call.

Can I catch the changed event from a manually opened Autocomplete?
Do you know any better Workarounds for my problem?

Here my current attempt:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilderService } from '../../../services/form-builder.service';
import { FormMetadataService } from '../../../services/form-metadata.service';
import { CustomAutocompleteComponent } from './custom-autocomplete.component';
import { MatAutocompleteTrigger, MatAutocomplete, MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-autocomplete-numeric',
  templateUrl: './custom-autocomplete-numeric.component.html'
})
export class CustomAutocompleteNumericComponent extends CustomAutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('faketrigger', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) faketrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
  @ViewChild('faketrigger') faketextbox: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('auto', { read: MatAutocomplete }) auto: MatAutocomplete;
  @ViewChild('textbox') textbox: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    formDataService: FormBuilderService,
    metadataService: FormMetadataService) {
    super(formDataService, metadataService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.auto.optionSelected.subscribe(_ => this.setSelectedValue(_));
  }

  private setSelectedValue(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.textbox.nativeElement.value = event.option.value;
  }

  public openAutocomplete(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.faketrigger.openPanel();
    }, 200);
  }
  public closeAutocomplete(): void {
    this.faketrigger.closePanel();
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <span *ngIf="prefix" matPrefix>{{prefix}} &nbsp;</span>
    <input class="numeric" [placeholder]="customPlaceholder" [formControl]="customFormControl" matInput #textbox
      [appHelp]="name" [appFormat]="customFormControl" (focus)="openAutocomplete()" (blur)="closeAutocomplete()">
    <span *ngIf="suffix" matSuffix>&nbsp;{{suffix}}</span>
  </mat-form-field>
  
  <mat-form-field>
    <input [matAutocomplete]="auto" #faketrigger style="display: block" matInput>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let o of options" [value]="o.Value" [attr.image]="o.Key">{{o.Value}}</mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the onSelectionChange is not documented or something. This will allow you to do something with the value after you change the selection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362070/angular-6-how-to-access-all-option-values-in-mat-autocomplete-dropdown/52362147#52362147

Comment: Unfortunately not. onSelectionChange is only triggered if the box is opend by the connected input. If I open the box via MatAutocompleteTrigger.openPanel(), the event does not trigger.

Comment: Is it the not better to focus the input and open the panel?

Comment: Not really, in this case I don't see the cursor for editing in the input field.